# ssh key forwarding not working under i3wm

Tags: lubuntu, ssh, i3-wm, ssh-agent

I recently switched from the regular Lubuntu LXDE/openbox to the i3 window manager under Lubuntu 16.04.

In either environment I can ssh with authentication forwarding activated into another machine via a vpn tunnel using:

```
ssh -A user@remote-machineA
```

On my local machine I have a ssh key for a git repository on remote-machineB. I can access the repository fine while on remote-machineA with LXDE but get a "Permission denied" using i3 to start with. Assuming my i3 does not forward keys like LXDE does. But I don't know what the missing piece is.

I came across this: https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/4ho1qj/sshagent_within_i3wm_on_ubuntu_1604_does_not_work/

But unsure if this is the same problem as I experience, I tried the solutions proposed there but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain DE environments starts their own applications that can behave as a `ssh-agent` and that can be forwarded. But it is not probably the case for the `i3`. If you want to use "ssh-agent forwarding" (it is not "authentication forwarding" as you note), you need to have `ssh-agent` running and your keys loaded inside. You can verify that simply using command below. It should list your authentication keys

```
ssh-add -l
```

If it returns error, you need to start the agent first:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

If it does not list them, you need to add the keys to the agent:

```
ssh-add path/to/key
```

If you want to automate it, add these commands to your `.bashrc` (do not start new agent with every bash! Only if there is no ssh-agent connection yet). There is a lot of snippet you can use all over the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much, `ssh-add mykey` solved it :)